# Python GTK3 inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

How can I inherit a GTK+3 class in python ? I'm trying to create a inherited class of Gtk.Application and what I got is a segfault.

I've tried a lot of things, but with this I got a segfault:

```
class Program(Gtk.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)

...
prg = Program.new("app_id", flags)
```

Comment: Did you call `gobject.type_register` on the class?

Comment: @user4815162342, no, can you give me a example of this ?

Comment: Simply call `gobject.type_register(Program)` after the class definition.

Comment: I'm no longer getting segfault, only the error `TypeError: Application constructor cannot be used to create instances of a subclass PyISGUI`

Comment: Why are you calling `Program.new()` to create the instance? One would expect that calling `Program(args...)` should be sufficient to instantiate the class.

Comment: AFAIK, in the bindings of gtk+3 the objects are created by the `new` static method, http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/api/Gtk_3.0/classes/Application.html#Gtk.Application.new

Comment: But then the Python-level constructor has not had a chance to run. On my system I get the `TypeError` even without the call to `type_register`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I try your code snippet I actually get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyclass.py", line 12, in <module>
    prg = Program.new("app_id", 0)
TypeError: Application constructor cannot be used to create instances of a subclass Program
```

which is expected, since you're trying to call the Python wrapper for `gtk_application_new()` by using `Program.new()`.

you should use the Python constructor form:

```
class Program(Gtk.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Application.__init__(self,
                                 application_id="org.example.Foo", 
                                 flags=Gio.ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE)

prg = Program()
sys.exit(prg.run(sys.argv));
```

this will actually warn you that you haven't implemented the `GApplication::activate` virtual function, which can be achieved by overriding the `do_activate` virtual method in your `Program` class:

```
class Program(Gtk.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Application.__init__(self,
                                 application_id="org.example.Foo",
                                 flags=Gio.ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE)
    def do_activate(self):
        print("Activated!")
```

this will print `Activated!` on the console, before quitting.

Comment: I'm getting segfault here implementing this in script, but I'll try to find what's causing this, since isn't the example you give, I've tried and doesn't cause segfault.